# Employer Terminated employee during covid-19 crises

Tags: canada, ontario, employer

From the past six months, I was working for a tech company as an Independent Contractor in the province of Ontario. The contract states that *"At the end of the ninety-day probationary period, the position will be reviewed, and if satisfactory, the continuation of this contract will be confirmed at a rate and engagement model agreed by both parties."*

After 90 days of my contact, I started approaching my Boss who is also the MD of the company. He promised me to put me on payroll (verbally) and make me a full-time employee. As I was on a Canadian Work Permit he even said that he can also help me with my Permanent Residency. So I followed by sending my PNP (PR) documents to him via email.

Two weeks went by and in my 5 months when I don't see any ongoing communication from him regarding my Full-time employment and PR. I approached him again and asked him which then he said that the Month of February is our Financial year and I have to wait.

Here come march and Still no talks from him regarding my situation. I booked some time with him to go over my situation and then he started to point gaps in my performance and said that I have to wait for more. On April 1, 2020, he terminated me from the company during the ongoing crises of COVID-19 when I need the job desperately. As no other company is hiring right now. I was furious and was not sure If I can do any Legal action about it.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.